# Firebase AngularFire using $priority and the $save overwrites the object

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Based on the [AngularFire documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-priority) I'm trying to set `$priority` on an object, then use `$save()` to update the data on Firebase.
The result I get instead is the object getting overwritten as empty (it's entry in Firebase). 
Here is my code

```
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseListPath);
    var myList = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

    myList.$add({
      created: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      user: userId
    }).then(function(newItemRef){
      var newItemObj = $firebase(newItemRef).$asObject();
      newItemObj.$priority = userId;
      newItemObj .$save();
    });
```

Comment: Can you try `$firebase(ref).$update(netItemObj.$id, newItemObj)`? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-update-key-data. Or pass `$priority` or `.priority` straight into `$add`, instead of waiting for the promise to fulfil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the priority directly into $add:

```
myList.$add({
   created: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
   user: userId,
   $priority: userId
});
```

There is also no reason to call $asArray and $asObject on the same synchronized data (it's already synchronized). This would work in your current model, but be unnecessary:

```
myList.$add({
  created: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  user: userId
}).then(function(newItemRef){
  var item = myList.$getRecord(newItemRef.name());
  item.$priority = userId;
  myList.$save(item);
});
```

However, there is really no reason to be using AngularFire here. If you aren't binding anything to the view, then you can simply make the call directly to the ref:

```
var ref = new Firebase(firebaseListPath);
ref.push().setWithPriority({ ... }, userId);
```